# obtener un pdf desde un webservice

Tags: genexus

Necesito consumir un webservice que devuelve la impresión de un documento en formato pdf, alguien sabe como puedo hacerlo con Genexus. Gx X Evo 1 U8

Logro obtener el string completo con "&resmensaje = &HttpClient.ToString()", pero no se cómo capturar la parte que contiene el documento en pdf.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

No se en que formato estarás recibiendo el PDF pero generalmente se retorna en Base64 (para validar si el hash que recibis es base64 podes ingresarlo en https://base64.guru/converter/decode/pdf y corroborar si te lo genera en un pdf valido) de ser así lo que tenés que hacer es agregarlo a un una variable del tipo file y luego crear el archivo localmente de la siguiente forma:

```
&File.Source = 'c:\temp\archivonombre.pdf'
&File.FromBase64String(&Sdtrespuesta.pdf)
&File.Create()
```